# Asp.net MVC Controller endpoint not reachable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatables, sitefinity

I'm trying to implement ServerSide Processing using ASP.net MVC but the problem is when I load my project only the Index endpoint of my controller is getting hits and the path that I specified for loading data not reachable by my project so nothing loaded in my data table.
:
created code by Sitefinity does not contain Route.config so I could not check the path of controller functions but as I know the path of any controller will become like this "/Controlleername/functionname"

Controller:

```
 [ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "Test", Title = "Test Page", SectionName = "MyCustom")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult LoadData()// I put Breakpoint here and nothing reached 
        {
            TestModel test = new TestModel();
            test.name = "name1";
            test.lastname = "lastnmae1";

            test.name = "name2";
            test.lastname = "lastnmae2";

            return Json(test);

        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>lastname</th>
           
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

@* Load datatable css *@
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section Scripts{
    @* Load DataTable js here *@

    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myTable").DataTable({
                "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                "serverSide": true, // for process server side
                "filter": false, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Test/LoadData",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "name", "name": "name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "lastname", "name": "lastname", "autoWidth": true },
                        
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Model:

```
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }

    }
```

**Update**:
and when I use custom Route by Annotation also not working and I think the reason related to [this](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/relativeroute-and-route-attributes-not-working) but the problem is I'm working on Visual studio IIS and also localhost I believe this causes by Sitefinity but I don't know how to work around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your widget to a page that has a url of /Test ?

Only then you can expect that /test/loadData will be reached

Comment: but that not a good practise how could I know any page name that the widget will be added to?

Comment: You can always use the Request.Url to get the url of the page where the widget is dropped and then append the action name. Or use the Url.Action("loadData") which is even better